# SQLAlchemy date field not updating with server_onupdate

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

Using SQLAlchemy with flask_sqlalchemy and alembic for PostgreSQL.  I have the following definition for a field:

```
date_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), server_onupdate=db.func.now())
```

However the field never updates when the record is modified.  It is set on create and never updates.  This is what is generated by alembic to create the table:

```
sa.Column('date_updated', sa.DateTime(), server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=True),
```

So it's no wonder that it's not being updated, since the server_onupdate param doesn't seem to be getting past alembic.

I'm not sure of the right way to do this.  The SQLAlchemy documentation is frustratingly complex and unclear where this is concerned.

Edit: From looking at how to do this in PostgreSQL directly, it looks like it requires the use of triggers.  I would prefer to do it at the DB level rather than at the application level if possible, but I don't know if I can add a trigger through SQLAlchemy.  I can add it directly at the DB but that could break when migrations are applied.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late, but for someone else who is met with this issue in the future, it would be good to note that onupdate runs when an actual change is made to the record on the database.

Requests with the same existing data will not trigger the onupdate function, as this does not trigger an actual change on the database record.

you can read more about this in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/dml.html), see also [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#column-table-metadata-api).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The way you say "I'm not sure of the right way to do this", I'm not sure if you mean specifically updating the date on the server side, or just updating it in general.

If you just want to update it and it doesn't matter how, the cleanest way in my opinion is to use event listeners.

Here's an example using the normal `sqlalchemy`, it will probably be the same (or at least very similar) in `flask-sqlalchemy`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(YourModel, 'before_insert')
@event.listens_for(YourModel, 'before_update')
def date_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    target.date_updated = datetime.utcnow()
```